# Can Blender do this type of object wraping like Wrap3

Tags: mesh

So basically is there a way in blender to wrap 1 body mesh to another body mesh. in which way that would put the UV of mesh 1 into mesh 2. The video link is about how WrapX|R3DS manage to do such thing [Wrap3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n_jNc2d5KX0&t=103s)

Comment: The timestamp you postet just shows some vertex selection. could you clarify what you want to do? I'm not gonna sit there and watch a 15min video just to guess wich part you are referring to.

Comment: sorry for the confusion of the link, I thought it would put you at the beginning of the video where the narrator would summarize the whole point of the video - wrap mesh 1 into mesh 2 and preserve mesh 1 UV in the body of mesh 2. I edited the question for more transparency